# git clean does not clean unwanted folder

Tags: git

I have a .NET solution which, after switching back to master branch, leaves a project folder behind. I want to clean this folder up (there is nothing but bin and obj folders inside, with some old dll's) so I tried `git clean -f -d`. This did not work.

I checked which files are being tracked by git using `git ls-tree test/flat -r --name-only` and sure enough the project folder to be cleaned is not listed.

What should I do to convince git to clean the working folder so that it's contents is only what is in the master branch?

Note: The unwanted project folder is also not ignored.

Comment: To clean ignored files (build outputs), use the `-x` option.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If there are ignored files in that folder, `git clean` won't remove the folder.

The options you want to look into, possibly using all three of them are:

- `-f`: force git clean to delete the files
- `-d`: delete untracked directories in addition to untracked files
- `-x`: delete files that are ignored by git

This command:

```
git clean -fdx
```

Should remove *all* untracked files and directories.

**NOTE!** And I say this because many doesn't read the warning labels, if you do this, you can't get those files back. They're gone. You will need to have disk- or file-level backup *other than git* to restore those files.

Use "**git clean -ifdx**" to delete files and directories interactively. This way you can avoid accidental delete of a file. Git shows you the list of file that will be deleted and asks you to choose from the option.

[image]

Comment: Apparently there is a bug in git: if a file is a "socket file", it will be ignored with `fdx` and whatever other options you may pass.

Answer (score 1):

`git clean` will not remove files that are being ignored by git by default.

Add the [-x flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#git-clean--x) to remove ignored files as well or the [-X flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#git-clean--X) to remove only ignored files and directories

```
git clean -fdx
git clean -fdX
```